# Consulta Count SQL com porcentagem em PHP

Tags: sql, porcentagem

Estou fazendo um relatório e preciso contar e exibir o número mais a porcentagem referente ao total da contagem. Com este código eu já faço a contagem. É possível exibir a porcentagem ao lado usando sql e php?

```
$sql = "SELECT
    customer.country,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    customer
INNER JOIN 
    booking ON booking.customer_id = customer.id
WHERE 
    (checkin >= '$datainicialsql' AND checkout <= '$datafinalsql')
GROUP BY country";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

$w = 0;

        while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  echo $result['country'] . " - " . $result['count'] . "<br/>";
}
```

Queria fazer um output assim:

```
BR 20 (20%)
IT 40 (40%)
PT 40 (40%)
```

Comment: Apesar de ser possível fazer isso numa única *query* julgo que ela não será muito eficiente. Sugiro, em alternativa, que faça primeiro uma consulta para obter o total de registos. Use depois esse valor, em conjunto com o resultado da segunda consulta, para calcular a percentagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode iterar duas vezes o resultado da consulta. Uma para calcular o total e outra para exibir os dados.

```
$result = array();
$total = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $result[] = $row;
    $total += $row['count'];
}
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row['country'] . ' - ' . $row['count'] . ' - (';
    echo (100 * $row['count'] / $total) . '%)<br/>';
}
```

---

Outro ponto, vi que você utiliza as funções `mysql_*`, mas essa extensão do PHP além de ser pouco segura, será descontinuada, sugiro utilizar a extensão [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php) (ainda sem tradução)

Comment: A solução ficou muito boa. Obrigado.
A respeito do PDO. Você tem ideia de quando a solução vai ser descontinuada?

Comment: de acordo com a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php): "Essa extensão se tornou obsoleta no PHP 5.5.0 e será removida no futuro"

Comment: O output de porcentagem não esta aparecendo. Agora que populei a tabela que percebi.

Comment: BR - 48 - (0%)
CL - 2 - (0%)
ES - 2 - (0%)
FR - 4 - (0%)
GB - 2 - (0%)
IT - 6 - (0%)
VAZIO - 2 - (0%)

Comment: Resolvido :D

echo (100 * $row['count'] / $total) . '%)<br/>';

Comment: atualizada a resposta